# AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'qualified_name' | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I'm tryna make a help command. But when I run `>help <cmd>`

I get this error:

`AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'qualified_name'`

Here is the code:

````
class HelpCommand(commands.HelpCommand):
    color = 0x171616

    def footer(self):
        return f"{self.clean_prefix}{self.invoked_with} <command> for more details"

    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return f"```yaml\n{self.clean_prefix}{command.qualified_name} {command.signature}```"

    async def send_cog_help(self, cog):
        em = discord.Embed(
            title=f"***{cog.qualified_name}** Commands", colour=self.color)
        if cog.description:
            em.description = cog.description

        filtered = await self.filter_commands(cog.get_commmands(), sort=True)
        for command in filtered:
            em.add_field(name=command.qualified_name,
                         value=command.short_doc or "No Description Provided")

        em.set_footer(text=self.footer())
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=em)

    async def send_command_help(self, command):
        em = discord.Embed(title=command.qualified_name, color=self.color)
        if command.help:
            em.description = command.help

        em.add_field(name="Syntax", value=self.get_command_signature(commands))
        em.set_footer(text=self.footer())
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=em)

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        em = discord.Embed(title="Loofah Help", color=self.color)
        for cog, commands in mapping.items():
            if not cog:
                continue

            filtered = await self.filter_commands(commands, sort=True)
            if filtered:
                value = "\t".join(f"`{i.name}`" for i in commands)
                em.add_field(name=cog.qualified_name, value=value)
        em.set_footer(text=self.footer())
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=em)
````

Full traceback error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\help.py", line 882, in command_callback
    return await self.send_command_help(cmd)
  File "D:\Kunnu\Loofah Rewrite\cogs\help.py", line 34, in send_command_help
    em.add_field(name="Syntax", value=self.get_command_signature(commands))
  File "D:\Kunnu\Loofah Rewrite\cogs\help.py", line 13, in get_command_signature
    return f"```yaml\n{self.clean_prefix}{command.qualified_name} {command.signature}```"
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'qualified_name'
````

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to pass `command`?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Sorry bro idk about that....I didn't know how to make a help command so I followed this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hcwf4nWcRiM&list=PLW4oa-YfAFMR4jt14xgQUA9qMN2tzF4l9&index=3`. Sorry...